# Is it possible to generate a hash value for all columns in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to generate a hash value for every record in my table. I am inserting records from 1 SQL database to another. My source and target tables are the same except in the target table I have an additional hash_dif column. How do I create a hash value based off the columns I have in my table and then insert that hash value into my target table along with all the data that I am selecting from the source table?

I want to:

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.SOURCE_TABLE
```

And I also want to generate a hash value like this:

```
select HashBytes('md5',convert(varbinary(max),(SELECT * FROM DBO.SOURCE_TABLE FOR XML AUTO))) as hash1
```

I'm confused how am I supposed to select all the data from the source while generating the hash value and then selecting that hash value all in one?

Comment: Only `CHECKSUM` and `BINARY_CHECKSUM` allow `*` but even these *don't* allow excluding columns like the hash column. What are you trying to do anyway? It's possible there are better ways that *don't* need hashing to detect changes at all. All SQL Server versions and editions offer features like change tracking and change data capture that can return all the rows changes since the last sync, included deleted ones

Comment: well im trying to select * columns from the source table that doesn't have the hash column, only the target table does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option if you don't want to specify all the columns.

```
Select A.*
      ,B.HB
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( hashbytes('SHA2_512',(Select A.* for JSON PATH) ) ) ) B(HB)
```

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECTLY! it's exactly what i needed thank you! now i need to do the same thing for the hash_key column!

Comment: A hash of a hash?   Why not  Select hashbytes('SHA2_512',( Select * from YourTable for JSON Path) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the HASHBYTES function and a subquery.
Here's an example query:

```
INSERT INTO DBO.TARGET_TABLE (col1, col2, col3, hash_diff)
SELECT 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    HASHBYTES('md5', CONVERT(varbinary(max), (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM DBO.SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SOURCE_TABLE.ID = TARGET_TABLE.ID FOR XML AUTO))) as hash_diff
FROM DBO.SOURCE_TABLE
```

Comment: You'd be much better off not using the `FROM` - e.g. `SELECT col1, col2, col3, HASHBYTES('md5', CONVERT(varbinary(max), (SELECT st.col1, st.col2, st.col3 FOR XML PATH))) as hash_diff FROM DBO.SOURCE_TABLE st`

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate all columns like below, NULL Values have to be converted and numbers also

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test1 (c1 NVARCHAR(32), c2 NVARCHAR(32));  
INSERT dbo.Test1 VALUES ('This is a test.','withanotherstring');  
INSERT dbo.Test1 VALUES ('This is test 2.', 'yetanaitherstring');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(c1,c2)) FROM dbo.Test1;
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 0x5E084B7988679136039B6B566496720BCBAB1BD965C0F071DA27AE2833B0B46C |
| 0x731F2E0E7955C2625CDE41D652C5ADC440BDFE5AF430135FC76894ED8E38E6C9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fxgT7rZL)